# Computation of infinite series containing Zeta function

Tags: numerics, special-functions, summation

(this is my first question on this forum I'm totally inexperienced in mathematica)

Consider the given alternating series:

$$f(x) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2a_n(x-1)^{2n+1}}{\zeta(-2n-1)}$$

Here, $a_n= (1+\frac{1}{4n+1})^6(1-\frac{1}{4n+3})^6(\frac{4n²}{4n²-1})²$

I need values of this series for atleast upto x=100 accurately.

Comment: Have you considered cross-posting at the [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Start by defining a function "a[n]" as a[n_]:=(1+1/(4n+1))^6 .  . . and so forth.  Then check it, type a[4] for example in the notebook, hit Enter.  Once you got that, then work on the sum as Sum[a[k],{k,1,myMax}].  Check that with some values.  Then define your function f[x_,n_]:=Sum[(a[k],rest of it),{k,1,n}].  Note the underscores.  Then check say, f[1.5,100]  see what happens.  Oh yeah, zeta function is Zeta[z] and gamma function is Gamma[z].

Comment: @Roman thank you for the advice sir; I will now.

Comment: @Dominic thank you for the comment. I'll try to follow your instructions.

Comment: Do you want values for `x` up to `100` or do you want partial sums up to the term for `n = 100`?

Comment: @murray corrected it

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk how sir? Can you explain?

Comment: Have you seen `NSum[]` already?